# Attach not checked checkboxes  callback on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, checkbox

So I have a gridview with a checkbox field.  In jquery, I'd like to write a function that does something when an unchecked checkbox is checked.

```
function clickAllSize() {
    alert("helloy");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input :checkbox:not(checked)").change(clickAllSize());
});
```

The problem is that the function is running immediately on pageload, before any clicking.  Subsequent checking/unchecking does not trigger the alert.

Comment: You should remove the space between input and :checkbox

Comment: And even better => `$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(checked)')`

Comment: When the DOM is ready, are there checkboxes rendered already? If not, you should use `on` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(checked)').change(clickAllSize);
});
```

1. In the change callback you should give the function name, not calling it.
2. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

> because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead.

Jquery is designed to work with **0+** selected elements, so always when you debug JQuery code check what is the selector length:

```
var amount = $("input :checkbox:not(checked)").length;
alert(amount);  // -Probably 0...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the () after `change(clickAllSize())`

Comment: Now it doesn't ever throw an alert